# How to configure claws mail to work with outlook?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have the servers and ports of the smtp/imap/pop3, but claws cant connect to receive or send mail, it says there is a timeout error.
I was working with thunderbird, but suddenly it stops to receive/send mails too.

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication activated ? If yes, you will need to use an app password rather than your normal password. The procedure to generate an app password is described here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944

Comment: No, I dont use the 2-factor in this account in particular

Comment: [Claws-Mail: Setting up OAuth 2.0 for Microsoft - for Outlook or Exchange](https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Oauth2#Setting_up_OAuth_2.0_for_Microsoft_-_for_Outlook_or_Exchange)